# Universal closure operation examples

Tags: category-theory, solution-verification, topos-theory, grothendieck-topologies

A universal closure operation on a topos $\mathcal{E}$ is a family of functions $c_{(-)}: Sub(-) \to Sub(-)$ such that for $A$ a subobject of $X$ we have

1. $A \leq c_X(A)$
2. $c_X(c_X(A)) = c_X(A)$
3. For any $f: Y \to X$, we have that $c_Y(f^*(A)) = f^*(c_X(A))$.

I am looking for non-trivial examples. As universal closure operations are in bijection with Lawvere-Tierney topologies, there are no intersting ones on Set. Another archetypical example is the category of presheaves. If we take $\mathcal{C}$ to be a topology regarded as a poset, we have a Grothendieck topology that says a sieve on $U$ (family of subsets of $U$) is covering if and only if those subsets cover $U$. But the associated Lawvere-Tierney topology is given by

$$J_U( (O_i \subseteq U)_{i \in I} ) = \{V \subseteq U \ | \ ((V \subseteq U)^*(O_i))_{i \in I} \textrm{ covers } V \}$$

which is the maximal sieve as $(V \subseteq U)^*(O) = V \cap O$. And the associated closure operation sends a subobject $A$ of $X$ to the identity on $X$, so this one is not interesting either.

Do you have any easy to work with examples? I was surprised I couldn't find one by using google.

**Edit:** actually, is there a mistake in the previous paragraph? There is a bijection between Grothendieck topologies and Lawvere-Tierney topologies, but the Grothendieck topology that has only the maximal sieve as a covering sieve, gives rise to the same Lawvere-Tierney topology.

Comment: The universal closure operation for presheaves on a topological space sends a monomorphism $F\to G$ of presheaves, with $G$ a sheaf, to the intersection of all subsheaves of $G$ containing $F$. So it is in fact interesting.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Could you explain where the mistake in my 'proof' that the universal closure operation sends mono $F \to G$ to $G$?

Comment: I’m a bit confused by what you were writing there. You seem to be applying the topology to a covering of $U$, rather than to a subobject of a presheaf?

Comment: I'm using the Grothendieck topology --> Lawvere-Tierney topology --> closure operation equivalence such as described on page 102 of https://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~ooste110/syllabi/cattop16.pdf . So $J_U$ is a morphism from the subobject classifier to itself, and in this case the subobject classifier assigns is the set of all open subsets of $U$ to $U$. Then the associated closure operation $F \subseteq G$ is given by $\overline{F}(U) = \{x \in GU \ | \ J_U (\phi_U(x)) = max(U)\}$, but this is $GU$ because $J_U$ sends everything to the maximal sieve.

Comment: Right, I'm with you now. Note that $(O_i)$ is an arbitrary sieve on $U$, for instance it could be generated by some proper subset $V\subsetneq U$, or even be empty. So in fact $J_U$ only sends $(O_i)$ to the maximal sieve if the $O_i$ do in fact cover $U$.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Right, thanks.